# Why does __invoke not show in ReflectionClass::getMethods result for a closure, but ReflectionClass::hasMethod("__invoke") returns true?

Tags: php, reflection, closures

I'm experimenting with reflection and trying to understand closures. 
Here's my code (PHP version is 5.6):

```
function closureWithState ($name) {
    return function () use ($name) { // 'use' keyword attaches the closure state
        return strToUpper($name);
    };
}

$closure = closureWithState('Foo');

$reflector = new ReflectionClass($closure);
$methods = $reflector->getMethods();
foreach ($methods as $method) {
    echo $method->getName() . PHP_EOL;
}

echo "Result of hasMethod for __invoke: " .$reflector->hasMethod("__invoke") . PHP_EOL;
```

and my output is

```
__construct
bind
bindTo
Result of hasMethod for __invoke: 1
```

So it seems that `getMethods` returns the methods *__construct*, *bind*,and *bindTo* but not *__invoke*. But when I test for `hasMethod("__invoke")` it returns `true`.

What is happening here?

Comment: Does a closure have an real `__construct`? Or maybe it is not shown because `__invoke` is mostly for classes to act like an function. So maybe thats the reason that is not expli. shown, but the functionallty is given by default. And maybe (the 3th) that is the reason why hasMethod gives true (expli. ask for `__invoke`) but getMethod ignores it. If that makes no sence, then write a bug report on php.net

Comment: I think that with reflection you won't get the list of magic methods. Try using reflection with a class in which you define magic methods.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but the reflection shows __construct ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ReflectionObject` here instead of `ReflectionClass`:

```
<?php

$closure = function () {};

$reflection = new \ReflectionObject($closure);

$methodNames = array_map(function (\ReflectionMethod $method) {
    return $method->getName();
},  $reflection->getMethods());

var_dump($methodNames);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/LDGJM